# What is the difference between specifying the column name inside or outside the .loc?

Tags: pandas

What is the difference between specifying the column name inside or outside the .loc?

For example:

```
df.loc[df['col1']>100]['col2']
```

vs

```
df.loc[df['col1']>100,'col2']
```

Comment: I suppose [this article](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) can help

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use second variant, because its a single operation.

In the first variant you add additional action, it is considered not as efficient.

In short
`df.loc[df['col1']>100,'col2']` is better than `df.loc[df['col1']>100]['col2']`

Comment: Other than performance, are both the same? For exmaple do both return copy/view? And do both have same concept on mutability?

Comment: Yes they have same result